# In Jenkins how do I properly set up a scm object and provide meta information on the build overview page?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit

In a Jenkins / git / Gerrit setup I currently maintain a bunch of "`pipeline-scm`" jobs: e.g. one of them gets triggered by Gerrit on an incoming change request in order to validate this change.
There is a "Gerrit Trigger" plugin for Jenkins that provides that provides job with a git refspec and the branch that change relates to - among lots of other details.
When you setup a "Pipeline script from SCM" a job instance (build) will be provided with an `scm` object which can be used to `checkout` the change and also gets used by Jenkins itself to show some meta information on the build's overview, e.g. the commits that define this change:

[image]

Now here comes my problem:

For [..] reasons I need to turn this "Pipeline script from SCM" job into a "Pipeline script" job. I.e. instead of just using the auto-generated `scm` object (which is being used on the `master` node already to fetch the pipeline script (and most likely to utilize the meta information about this change)) to run `checkout scm` in my pipeline script I now have to create this object manually:

```
scm = [
    $class: "GitSCM",
    userRemoteConfigs: [[
        credentialsId: <SOME ID>,
        url: <REPO-URL>,
    ]],
    branches: [[
        name: <BRANCH-NAME>,
    ]],
]

checkout scm
```

This raises two questions:

1. I know the Gerrit plugin provides details about a change in environment variables like `GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION`, `GERRIT_REFSPEC` and `GERRIT_BRANCH` - but how do I use them? I've seen [examples](https://www.pbworks.net/jenkins-checkout-gerrit-patchset-gerrit-trigger-plugin/) which define `branches` using `GERRIT_BRANCH`, others use `GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION` others use a branch pattern like `*/master`.
2. how does the meta information which can be extracted from a valid `scm` instance get to the build's overview page? I guess the `pipeline-scm` mechanism makes the master node populate this page automatically, but now the master node has no `scm` object in advance anymore. Is there a mechanism like "currentBuild.updateMetaInfo(scm)`?

Is there any documentation about how to properly set up and use a `scm` object (as Jenkins does) in a standalone pipeline job (i.e. without the scm mechanism)?

**Update**:
This `scm` configuration works for me in terms of *checkout*:

```
scm = [
    $class: "GitSCM",
    userRemoteConfigs: [[
        credentialsId: <MY_ID>,
        url: <MY_REPO_URL>,
        refspec: env["GERRIT_REFSPEC],
    ]],
    branches: [[name: "FETCH_HEAD"]],
];
```

Unfortunately even after `checkout scm` no "Changes" show up, instead the overview page only displays this:

[image]

The build matrix in the job overview also states there are no changes:
[image]

Comment: Why can't you use the example you linked? It should do what you want.

Comment: Not part of your question, but do you mind sharing what comes after the snippet you posted? I understand that you are converting from "Pipeline script from SCM" so I assume that after `checkout scm` there is some kind of "now execute this jenkinsfile in the checkout". Do you mind sharing how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if that answers your question - as you guessed correctly I run `checkout scm` and after that I load the "actual" groovy script and run a `main()` function I know it exists: `load("${checkout_dir}/path/to/job.groovy").main()`
The actual script file path is baked into the `pipline` script (generated with JJB)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question on how to use the GERRIT_ variables with the Jenkins Git SCM, check [the docs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gerrit-trigger/#plugin-content-usage-with-the-git-plugin):

> To get the Git Plugin to download your change; set Refspec to
> $GERRIT_REFSPEC and the Choosing strategy to Gerrit Trigger. This may
> be under ''Additional Behaviours/Strategy For Choosing What To Build'
> rather than directly visible as depicted in the screenshot. You may
> also need to set 'Branches to build' to $GERRIT_BRANCH. If this does
> not work for you set Refspec to refs/changes/:refs/changes/* and
> 'Branches to build' to *$GERRIT_REFSPEC.

Regarding the second one:

The `checkout` step should add the information to the build status page.

Regarding your closing question:

The scm object is just a convenience object that represents the scm you would configure in Pipeline from SCM, so you dont need to provide the details specified there in the Pipeline script again.

To generate a checkout step for a Pipeline without SCM, use the Snippet Generator from the Pipeline Syntax page.

Comment: which example do you mean? My own one doesn't define a specific branch and the two examples I've referenced use either `GERRIT_BRANCH` or `GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION`, while inspecting an `scm` object from a working `pipeline-scm` project gives me `refs/changes/*` instead. Using `GERRIT_BRANCH` results in `ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.` for me, while `GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION` works but won't report the list of commits..

Comment: I have clarified which example. The GERRIT_BRANCH behavior is strange. have you checked its value?

Comment: `GERRIT_BRACH` is something like `sandbox/its.me/jenkins-experiments` while `GERRIT_REFSPEC` looks like `refs/changes/41/41741/2`

Comment: I see. [the documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gerrit-trigger/#plugin-content-usage-with-the-git-plugin) has something on this, I'll expand my answer.